# How to keep track of executed CUDA blocks?

Tags: cuda

Just for the sake of testing my understanding of things, I decided to modify the vector addition found in the CUDA samples so that the kernel quits after a specific time and is then re-launched to complete. The way I achieve the "timeout" is by having a pinned variable that the host sets to 1 after some time. Within the kernel, a check of this variable is performed to determine whether execution should continue. If the thread continues its execution it is marked as complete. In order to test that each thread executes just once, I've modified the addition to `C[i] = C[i] + B[i]` This all works as expected; the device code looks as follows:

```
/* Function 
 *  Internal device function used for getting the current thread's global ID
 *  regardless of the block/grid configuration. It assumes that the 
 *  grid and block are 3 dimensional.
 *
 *  @return: The thread's global ID
 */
static __device__ int get_global_idx()
{
  int blockId = blockIdx.x 
    + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x 
    + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; 
  int threadId = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z)
    + (threadIdx.z * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y))
    + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x)
    + threadIdx.x;
  return threadId;
}

/* Function
 *  Device function that determines if the current thread should continue execution.
 *  A check should be used on the return value. If the timeout has not been set 
 *  and the thread has not previously executed the index at the thread's ID in the
 *  thread_ids array is set to 1 to indicate it was allowed to proceed.
 *
 *  @param thread_ids:  A pointer to the array with a size that matches the max number
 *                      of threads that will be spawned
 *   
 *  @param time_out:  Memory mapped variable used by the host to signal the kernel when
 *                    execution should suspend
 *
 *  @return:  A boolean value indicating whether the current thread should continue or not
 */
__device__ bool continue(unsigned int *thread_ids, volatile unsigned int *time_out)
{
    if(*time_out == 1){ 
      return false;
    }

    int tid = get_global_idx(); 

    if(thread_ids[tid] == 1)
    {
      return false;
    }
    thread_ids[tid] = 1;

    return true;
}

__global__ void
vectorAdd(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, long numElements, unsigned int *thread_ids, volatile unsigned int *timeout)
{
    if(!continue(thread_ids, timeout))
    {
       return;
    }

    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;


    if (i < numElements)
    {
       /* C[i] = A[i] + B[i]; */
       C[i] = C[i] + B[i]; //Modifed from above
    }
}
```

I considered how this may fail if __syncthreads() was used. So I decided to do block level suspension. Based on my understanding, I thought this would be simple. Keep track of if a block has started, and count how many threads have executed for that block and only suspend when all threads of an already started block have completed and deny any threads who's block has not started. So I used a struct and modified the continue function as follows:

```
typedef struct block_info_t{
  int started; /* Initialized to zero before any kernel launch */
  unsigned int thread_count;
}block_info;

__device__ bool continue(unsigned int *thread_ids, volatile unsigned int *time_out, block_info *b_info)
{
    int bid = blockIdx.x + gridDim.x * (blockIdx.y + gridDim.z * blockIdx.z);
    unsigned int bsize = blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z;

    if(*time_out == 1 && b_info[bid].started == 0)
    { 
      return false;
    }

    if(b_info[bid].thread_count == bsize)
    {
      return false;
    }

    b_info[bid].started = 1;
    atomicInc(&b_info[bid].thread_count, bsize); 

    return true;
}
```

This does not work, when I execute verification on the host (`h_B[i] - h_C[i]`) I don't get a consistent zero result. Which means that some threads somehow managed to execute multiple times. Any ideas how/why this is happening with the latter attempt? Thanks.

**I don't care about performance at this point; just trying to understand what is really happening.**

**EDIT**

Here is the complete code, compile with `nvcc file_name.cu` and execute `program_name <vector-length>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// For the CUDA runtime routines (prefixed with "cuda_")
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

typedef struct block_info_t{
  int started; /* Initialized to zero before any kernel launch */
  unsigned int thread_count;
}block_info;

__device__ bool continue_execution(volatile unsigned int *time_out, block_info *b_info)
{
    int bid = blockIdx.x + gridDim.x * (blockIdx.y + gridDim.z * blockIdx.z);
    unsigned int bsize = blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z;

    if(*time_out == 1 && b_info[bid].started == 0)
    { 
      return false;
    }

    if(b_info[bid].thread_count == bsize)
    {
      return false;
    }

    b_info[bid].started = 1;
    atomicInc(&b_info[bid].thread_count, bsize); 

    return true;
}

__global__ void
vectorAdd(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, long numElements, volatile unsigned int *time_out, block_info *b_info)
{
    if(!continue_execution(time_out, b_info))
    { 
      return;
    }

    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numElements)
    {
       //C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
       C[i] = C[i] + B[i]; //Modified from above
    }
}

void computation_complete(int *complete, int block_amt, block_info *h_block_info)
{
  size_t i;
  for(i = 0; i < block_amt; i++)
  {
    if(h_block_info[i].started == 1)
    {
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }
  *complete = (i == block_amt) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: <program-name> <vector-length>\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Print the vector length to be used, and compute its size
    long numElements = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
    printf("[Vector addition of %d elements]\n", numElements);

    float *h_A = (float *)malloc(size);
    float *h_B = (float *)malloc(size);
    float *h_C = (float *)malloc(size);

    // Initialize the host input vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        h_A[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_B[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_C[i] = 0.0;
    }

    float *d_A = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size);

    float *d_B = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size);

    float *d_C = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);

    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_C, h_C, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    size_t block_info_bytes = blocksPerGrid * sizeof(struct block_info_t);
    block_info *h_block_info = (struct block_info_t *)malloc(block_info_bytes);

    for(int i = 0; i < blocksPerGrid; i++)
    {
      h_block_info[i].started = 0;
      h_block_info[i].thread_count = 0;
    }

    block_info *d_block_info = NULL;
    cudaMalloc(&d_block_info, block_info_bytes);
    cudaMemcpy(d_block_info, h_block_info, block_info_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    volatile unsigned int *timeout = NULL;
    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&timeout, sizeof(volatile unsigned int), cudaHostAllocMapped);
    *timeout = 0;

    double quantum = 0.0001 * 1000000.0;
    double initial_quantum = quantum;

    int complete = 0;

    /* Here the kernel launch is looped until all blocks are complete */
    while(complete == 0)
    {
      vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, numElements, timeout, d_block_info);
      usleep(quantum);
      *timeout = 1;
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();

      cudaMemcpy(h_block_info, d_block_info, block_info_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
      computation_complete(&complete, blocksPerGrid, h_block_info);

      if(complete == 0)
      {
        quantum = quantum + initial_quantum;
        *timeout = 0;
      }
    }

    cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Verify that the result vector is correct
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        if (fabs(h_B[i] - h_C[i]) > 1e-5)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Result verification failed at element %d!\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Test PASSED\n");

    // Free device global memory
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);

    free(h_A);
    free(h_B);
    free(h_C);

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when asking "why isn't this code working?" you are [expected](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (<-- click here and read) to provide a [mcve].  What you have shown is not one.  It should be a complete code, that someone else can compile and run and see the issue, without having to add anything or change anything.  A kernel, by itself, is not a [mcve].

Comment: @RobertCrovella, Thanks. I've edited to include a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition in your `continue_execution` routine.  Consider the following scenario:

1. warp0 of a threadblock enters the `continue_execution` routine.  At the moment that it checks the variables `*time_out` and `b_info[bid].started` it witnesses those to be 0 and 0 respectively.  So it proceeds to the next if test.
2. warp1 of the same threadblock enters the `continue_execution` routine (let's say slightly later), and it witnesses the variables to be 1 and 0 respectively.  So it returns `false` and causes the warp1 threads to exit.
3. warp0 continues on and eventually sets `b_info[bid].started` to 1, and then updates the `thread_count`.  It then returns true and proceeds with the vector add.

I could continue with this, but I think if you consider the above 3 items carefully you will realize it is a case you did not account for.  Your implicit expectation is that every thread would read a coherent (i.e. the same across a given threadblock) value for `*time_out`.  But this is not guaranteed by your code, and if it fails to do so, then we end up with some threadblocks where some threads have completed their work and some have not.

So how could we fix this?  The above description should point the way.  One possible approach is to guarantee that for any given threadblock, that every thread gets the *same* value for `*time_out` whether it be 1 or 0.  One possible solution would be to make the following changes to the beginning of your `vectorAdd` kernel:

```
__shared__ volatile unsigned int my_time_out;
if (!threadIdx.x) my_time_out = *time_out;
__syncthreads();
if(!continue_execution(&my_time_out, b_info))
```

with those changes, we ensure that every thread in a block gets a coherent view of the time out variable, and according to my testing, the problem is resolved:

```
$ cat t100.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// For the CUDA runtime routines (prefixed with "cuda_")
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

typedef struct block_info_t{
  int started; /* Initialized to zero before any kernel launch */
  unsigned int thread_count;
}block_info;

__device__ bool continue_execution(volatile unsigned int *time_out, block_info *b_info)
{
    int bid = blockIdx.x + gridDim.x * (blockIdx.y + gridDim.z * blockIdx.z);
    unsigned int bsize = blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z;

    if(*time_out == 1 && b_info[bid].started == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }

    if(b_info[bid].thread_count == bsize)
    {
      return false;
    }

    b_info[bid].started = 1;
    atomicInc(&b_info[bid].thread_count, bsize);

    return true;
}

__global__ void
vectorAdd(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, long numElements, volatile unsigned int *time_out, block_info *b_info)
{
#ifdef USE_FIX
    __shared__ volatile unsigned int my_time_out;
    if (!threadIdx.x) my_time_out = *time_out;
    __syncthreads();
    if(!continue_execution(&my_time_out, b_info))
#else
    if(!continue_execution(time_out, b_info))
#endif
    {
      return;
    }

    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numElements)
    {
       //C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
       C[i] = C[i] + B[i]; //Modified from above
    }
}

void computation_complete(int *complete, int block_amt, block_info *h_block_info)
{
  size_t i;
  for(i = 0; i < block_amt; i++)
  {
    if(h_block_info[i].started == 1)
    {
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }
  *complete = (i == block_amt) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: <program-name> <vector-length>\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Print the vector length to be used, and compute its size
    long numElements = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
    printf("[Vector addition of %ld elements]\n", numElements);

    float *h_A = (float *)malloc(size);
    float *h_B = (float *)malloc(size);
    float *h_C = (float *)malloc(size);

    // Initialize the host input vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        h_A[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_B[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_C[i] = 0.0;
    }

    float *d_A = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size);

    float *d_B = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size);

    float *d_C = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);

    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_C, h_C, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;

    size_t block_info_bytes = blocksPerGrid * sizeof(struct block_info_t);
    block_info *h_block_info = (struct block_info_t *)malloc(block_info_bytes);

    for(int i = 0; i < blocksPerGrid; i++)
    {
      h_block_info[i].started = 0;
      h_block_info[i].thread_count = 0;
    }

    block_info *d_block_info = NULL;
    cudaMalloc(&d_block_info, block_info_bytes);
    cudaMemcpy(d_block_info, h_block_info, block_info_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    volatile unsigned int *timeout = NULL;
    cudaHostAlloc((void **)&timeout, sizeof(volatile unsigned int), cudaHostAllocMapped);
    *timeout = 0;

    double quantum = 0.0001 * 1000000.0;
    double initial_quantum = quantum;

    int complete = 0;

    /* Here the kernel launch is looped until all blocks are complete */
    while(complete == 0)
    {
      vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, numElements, timeout, d_block_info);
      usleep(quantum);
      *timeout = 1;
      cudaDeviceSynchronize();

      cudaMemcpy(h_block_info, d_block_info, block_info_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
      computation_complete(&complete, blocksPerGrid, h_block_info);

      if(complete == 0)
      {
        quantum = quantum + initial_quantum;
        *timeout = 0;
      }
    }

    cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Verify that the result vector is correct
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        if (fabs(h_B[i] - h_C[i]) > 1e-5)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Result verification failed at element %d!\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Test PASSED\n");

    // Free device global memory
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);

    free(h_A);
    free(h_B);
    free(h_C);

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t100 t100.cu
$ ./t100 327678
[Vector addition of 327678 elements]
Result verification failed at element 0!
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t100 t100.cu -DUSE_FIX
$ ./t100 327678
[Vector addition of 327678 elements]
Test PASSED
$ ./t100 327678
[Vector addition of 327678 elements]
Test PASSED
$ ./t100 327678
[Vector addition of 327678 elements]
Test PASSED
$
```

One other change I made to your code was in this line:

```
printf("[Vector addition of %d elements]\n", numElements);
```

this has no bearing on the problem, but your format specifier does not match your variable type.  Fix by changing to `%ld`.